# can not find the best database software for my data?

Tags: database

I have huge data and I want to create a database where I can easily search and analyze it.
I'm looking for a software that is easy to use and flexible, like I can add my own functions for example to look for entry's attribute that its value is less than 200.

my data includes date and 10 columns of numerical data.

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: what does 'huge' mean? How is the data structured? Even the most basic systems can handle simple comparison of attributes to constants.

Comment: "Shopping list" questions ("I'm looking for something. Please post some links") are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Google and Bing are both excellent at searching for things and returning links to the results. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this type of stuff with a simple Excel spreadsheet.

The other extreme would be to download MySQL and all of the associated components, learn PHP, HTML and JavaScript.

Depending on what you are doing the spreadsheet might be the best way.

Comment: Why learn PHP, HTML **and** JavaScript? In this case JavaScript is not very important. This could easily be done with a few lines of PHP...

Answer (score 1):

Any database can do that. How much data do you have ?

If its less than 2000 lines a spreadsheet will likely be best as its the most user friendly.

If its more complex maybe access

If it needs to be online mysql / postgres will likely be best.

The last 2 are the most flexible but will have a larger learning curve

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/), it is a server-less database, and it will give you for free most of the sql capabilities.
If needed, you can easily upgrade to mysql or other server based DB.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution than a stand-alone RDBMS like MySQL or Postres is [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/).

You can browse the [Implementation Limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) to verify whether your definition of "huge" is managable.